# How can i run multiple queries in parallel on hive with tez execution engine?

Tags: hive, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

We want to run hive with tez for querying data in hdfs as multiple users will query hive so we need to configure hive in such a way so that the queries get executed in parallel

As tez uses yarn for assigning resources to multiple nodes, we are trying to limit the containers getting assigned per query of hive in yarn but not able to find the proper config for that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

User Limit Factor is a way to control the max amount of resources that a single user can consume. I hope below Cloudera blog will help you.

[https://blog.cloudera.com/yarn-capacity-scheduler/#:~:text=User%20Limit%20Factor%20is%20a%20way%20to%20control%20the%20max%20amount%20of%20resources%20that%20a%20single%20user%20can%20consume](https://blog.cloudera.com/yarn-capacity-scheduler/#:%7E:text=User%20Limit%20Factor%20is%20a%20way%20to%20control%20the%20max%20amount%20of%20resources%20that%20a%20single%20user%20can%20consume)

Then we have Queue level AMshare as well.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/how-to-tune-yarn-scheduler-capacity-maximum-am-resource/td-p/289415